# Timestamp in execute block or stored procedure in Firebird doesn't work

Tags: sql, stored-procedures, timestamp, firebird

Why - when using this code block in Firebird - are the `v_start` and `v_end` variables always equal? And why does it always return null without a `suspend` statement?

```
execute block
returns (elapsed numeric(9,3),
v_start timestamp,
v_end timestamp)
as
declare variable i integer;
begin
   i = 1000000;
   v_start = current_timestamp;
   while (i > 0) do
       i = i - 1;

   v_end = current_timestamp;

   elapsed = v_end - v_start;

   suspend;
end
```

Answer (score 4):

Yes, the `current_timestamp` value stays constant within a PSQL module, this is [documented](http://www.firebirdsql.org/file/documentation/reference_manuals/fblangref25-en/html/fblangref25-functions-contextvars.html#fblangref25-contextvars-current_timestamp) (quote from notes section):

> Within a PSQL module (procedure, trigger or executable block), the value of CURRENT_TIMESTAMP will remain constant every time it is read. If multiple modules call or trigger each other, the value will remain constant throughout the duration of the outermost module. If you need a progressing value in PSQL (e.g. to measure time intervals), use 'NOW'.

The requirement to use `SUSPEND` is [documented](http://www.firebirdsql.org/file/documentation/reference_manuals/fblangref25-en/html/fblangref25-dml-execblock.html) too:

> If the block has output parameters, you must use SUSPEND or nothing will be returned.

Comment: The use of `SUSPEND` is not 100% required, but most query tools will execute it as a normal statement (or selectable stored procedure) instead of as an executable stored procedure; which means that they can't get the one row.

Answer (score 0):

With this code works as expected...

```
execute block
returns (elapsed bigint,
v_start timestamp,
v_end timestamp)
as
declare variable i integer;
begin
    i = 100000000;
    v_start = 'now';
    while (i > 0) do
        i = i - 1;

    v_end = 'now';

    elapsed = datediff (second from cast(:v_start as timestamp) to cast('now' as timestamp));

    suspend;
end
```